# bootstrap 4 multiple elements previous collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I added the bootstrap carousel and changed to display multiple items, although I have a problems

When I click on the next logo everything is ok, but when I click on the previous logo, appear multiple logos all together before to fix itself, What happens? How can I fix that problem?

Here a link to the project, live page and complete repo

LINKS REMOVED AS DON'T EXIST ANYMORE

Here the code:

```
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="10"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>HTML</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>CSS</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>SASS</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>Javascript</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>Jquery</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>React</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>webpack</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
            <h4>NPM</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Mate, if you expect to get any answers you need to post the relevant, testable code here. And in your case, there need to be live images in the code. Use a placeholder service or something.

Comment: ok, I thought that the live page with the whole code was enough, added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the numbering of your indicators was a bit messed up. Also, you have a bit much of custom css for my taste. So, I ripped it out and used native Bootstrap classes instead such as `mx-auto` (margin horizontal auto).

Check out this snippet and then start adding your own custom code bit by bit until you see where it breaks:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    body {
        background: black;
    }
    .carousel-inner {
        height: 300px;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .carousel-item img {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 250px;
    }
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mt-4">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>01 HTML</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>02 CSS</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>03 SASS</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>04 Javascript</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>05 Jquery</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>06 React</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>07 webpack</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/ci1BoK6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-block mx-auto">
                            <h4>08 NPM</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ok, thanks :) It has a lot of custom CSS because at the beginning the portfolio was just with custom CSS, I´m implementing Bootstrap just now